# Cant link stylesheet

Tags: html, css, amazon-ec2, noscript

I’m setting up a new website. I launched an Amazon EC2 instance with LAMP using Bitnami and I’m now starting to build the site, however when I try to link my index file (or any other) to my CSS file using the `<link>` tag all my CSS gets “imported” to the PHP file instead of creating the link.
I also get some `<noscript>` tags along my source code which I haven’t put there. Any idea were those are coming from?

This is my code so far:

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="page-wrap" class="home-page">

    <form id="compare" name="compare" method="get" action="compare.php">
        <input type="text" id="stocks" name="stocks" placeholder="Input Stocks Symbols to Compare">
    </form>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

And this is the source code that the browser is outputting:

```
<html> 

<head> 

<style>#page-wrap{width:960px;margin:0 auto}.home-page #compare{text-align:center;margin-top:200px}.home-page #compare #stocks{width:750px;height:55px;border:1px solid #ddd;border-bottom:2px solid #ccc;font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;color:#aaa;font-size:18px;text-transform:uppercase;text-align:center}.column{float:left;width:300px}</style> 

</head> 

<body><noscript><meta HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;url='http://wellmadestocks.com/?ModPagespeed=noscript'" /><style><!--table,div,span,font,p{display:none} --></style><div style="display:block">Please click <a href="http://wellmadestocks.com/?ModPagespeed=noscript">here</a> if you are not redirected within a few seconds.</div></noscript> 

<div id="page-wrap" class="home-page"> 

<form id="compare" name="compare" method="get" action="compare.php"> 
<input type="text" id="stocks" name="stocks" placeholder="Input Stocks Symbols to Compare"> 
</form> 

</div> 

<script pagespeed_no_defer="" type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
(function(){var e=encodeURIComponent,f=window,h=document,m="width",n="documentElement",p="height",q="length",r="prototype",s="body",t="&",u="&ci=",w="&n=",x="&rd=",y=",",z="?",A="Content-Type",B="Microsoft.XMLHTTP",C="Msxml2.XMLHTTP",D="POST",E="application/x-www-form-urlencoded",F="img",G="input",H="load",I="oh=",J="on",K="pagespeed_url_hash",L="url=",M=function(a,c,d){if(a.addEventListener)a.addEventListener(c,d,!1);else if(a.attachEvent)a.attachEvent(J+c,d);else{var b=a[J+c];a[J+c]=function(){d.call(this);b&&b.call(this)}}};f.pagespeed=f.pagespeed||{};var N=f.pagespeed,O=function(a,c,d,b,g){this.d=a;this.f=c;this.g=d;this.a=g;this.c={height:f.innerHeight||h[n].clientHeight||h[s].clientHeight,width:f.innerWidth||h[n].clientWidth||h[s].clientWidth};this.e=b;this.b={}};O[r].j=function(a){a=a.getBoundingClientRect();return{top:a.top+(void 0!==f.pageYOffset?f.pageYOffset:(h[n]||h[s].parentNode||h[s]).scrollTop),left:a.left+(void 0!==f.pageXOffset?f.pageXOffset:(h[n]||h[s].parentNode||h[s]).scrollLeft)}};O[r].i=function(a){if(0>=a.offsetWidth&&0>=a.offsetHeight)return!1;a=this.j(a);var c=a.top.toString()+y+a.left.toString();if(this.b.hasOwnProperty(c))return!1;this.b[c]=!0;return a.top<=this.c[p]&&a.left<=this.c[m]};O[r].l=function(){for(var a=[F,G],c=[],d={},b=0;b<a[q];++b)for(var g=h.getElementsByTagName(a[b]),k=0;k<g[q];++k){var v=g[k].getAttribute(K);v&&g[k].getBoundingClientRect&&this.i(g[k])&&!(v in d)&&(c.push(v),d[v]=!0)}b=!1;a=I+this.g;this.a&&(a+=w+this.a);if(0!=c[q]){a+=u+e(c[0]);for(b=1;b<c[q];++b){d=y+e(c[b]);if(131072<a[q]+d[q])break;a+=d}b=!0}this.e&&(d=x+e(JSON.stringify(this.h())),131072>=a[q]+d[q]&&(a+=d),b=!0);N.criticalImagesBeaconData=a;if(b){var c=this.d,b=this.f,l;if(f.XMLHttpRequest)l=new XMLHttpRequest;else if(f.ActiveXObject)try{l=new ActiveXObject(C)}catch(P){try{l=new ActiveXObject(B)}catch(Q){}}l&&(l.open(D,c+(-1==c.indexOf(z)?z:t)+L+e(b)),l.setRequestHeader(A,E),l.send(a))}};O[r].h=function(){for(var a={},c=h.getElementsByTagName(F),d=0;d<c[q];++d){var b=c[d],g=b.getAttribute(K);if("undefined"==typeof b.naturalWidth||"undefined"==typeof b.naturalHeight||"undefined"==typeof g)break;if("undefined"==typeof a[b.src]&&0<b[m]&&0<b[p]&&0<b.naturalWidth&&0<b.naturalHeight||"undefined"!=typeof a[b.src]&&b[m]>=a[b.src].n&&b[p]>=a[b.src].m)a[g]={renderedWidth:b[m],renderedHeight:b[p],originalWidth:b.naturalWidth,originalHeight:b.naturalHeight}}return a};N.k=function(a,c,d,b,g){var k=new O(a,c,d,b,g);M(f,H,function(){f.setTimeout(function(){k.l()},0)})};N.criticalImagesBeaconInit=N.k;})();pagespeed.criticalImagesBeaconInit('/mod_pagespeed_beacon','http://wellmadestocks.com/','O-_tWHm2s1',false,'BwP-b7zi7Po');
//]]></script></body> 

</html>
```

Any idea were all this might be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for this would be because Amazon is reading the CSS files with the wrong MIME type, and the `Content-Type` attribute is set incorrectly for the files, thus they are being read as another file type, probably simple `.txt` files, which are imported by the PHP script rather than displayed in the page as a `<link>` tag. To fix this, you'll need to [set a custom header](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--metadata-http-header-update-custom-metadata.html)/metadata on the files specifying the correct MIME type.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!
You are probably right, however I’ve been investigating and I’m not sure the link you provided will work for me. I’m new to AWS but I don’t think I’m using S3, just an EC2 instance. When I access my AWS console and navigate to S3 I see no buckets created, so there is nothing to set a custom header for there… :S

Comment: Don't know if [this](http://s3browser.com/features-content-mime-types-editor.php) will help, but it seems to be the most relevant S3 documentation I could find. Nothing on EC2 yet. Will keep you posted!

Comment: Still haven't found anything on EC2. Could it possibly be that you've named your file with a `.cs` extension on accident, which is by default handled as "text" by EC2?

Comment: I just double check and the file extension is correct :S

Comment: Well, I didnt really find a solution, but I did solve the problem... I just launched a new EC2 instance, this time using LEMP instead of LAMP. Everything seems to be working fine on this new instance.

Thank you so much for your help anyway! :)

Comment: @GuillermoCarone No problem! Glad you found a solution! I hope that if anyone stumbles upon this, we'll eventually have an answer!